# Querying a bitmap distinguishing 0-values

Tags: c++, c, bitmap, bit-manipulation

I'm writing a piece of software that will process huge amounts of data. For memory efficiency, some of the fields in the records being processed are stored in a single bitmap.

Using `#define`s I declared what both the position and the size of each field in the bitmap is.

Now I need a fast way to check against predefined values. My first attempt was this:

```
bool checkBit(unsigned short int a_bitMap, unsigned short int a_bitValue, unsigned short int a_bitPosition)
{
    // Values are always bit-0 based, so we need to shift here
    unsigned short int _value = (a_bitValue << a_bitPosition);
    return ((a_bitMap & _value) == _value);
}
```

Here, a_bitMap is the bitmap for the record being processed holding data for all fields, and a_bitValue is the (defined) coded value being checked (which would, in case of flags, always be 1).

This works and is fast, but this way I cannot use the value '0' as a coded value (so 3 bit give me only 7 options, not 8) so I came up with this solution:

```
bool checkBit(unsigned short int a_bitMap, unsigned short int a_bitValue, unsigned short int a_bitPosition, unsigned short int a_bitSize)
{
    static const unsigned short int bitmapSize = 8 * sizeof(a_bitMap);
    unsigned short int _shift = bitmapSize - (a_bitPosition + a_bitSize);
    a_bitMap = (a_bitMap << _shift);
    a_bitMap = (a_bitMap >> (a_bitPosition + _shift));
    return (a_bitMap == a_bitValue);
}
```

This works exactly the way I want... but it slows down the process dramatically. The number of records that need to be processed goes into the billions, so these extra shifts have a huge impact.
That's also why I'd like to avoid std::bitset, since billions of object instantiations gives too much overhead as well.

How can I do this while still being able to distinguish 0-values?

Comment: could you explain what the a_bitValue parameter contains?

Comment: Good one indeed :-/ I added this after the first codeblock in.

Comment: Manipulating bits is usually faster than accessing memory. Have you profiled your program to show the opposite ? have you turned optimizations on ?

Comment: In this case the bitmanipulations is extra... Optimizer is on. A program with a (tiny) test dataset ran 1'36 with the first method, 2'48" with the second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution I'd define and pass in a mask rather than position and size so if you wanted a 2 bit data from position 3 and 4 of an 8 bit map you'd define

```
#define mask = 0x18;//binary 00011000
```

then in check bit you just need to:

```
return (map & mask) == value;
```

Comment: If I need to check for the `XX` in `yyyXXzzz` and they need to be `10`, the value passed to the check method is 2, so yes, this works<br/>But I think using bitmasks is what I need :)

Comment: Of course, silly of me, remember that the example I've shown will compare value with 000XX000 not 000000XX

Comment: I understand indeed; the value must be shifted, but I can do that outside a loop now (these are - kinda - predefined... but let's not go into the functional aspects :) which will increase performance even more ;) Thnx again!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

```
bool checkBit(unsigned short int a_bitMap, unsigned short int a_bitPosition)
{
    unsigned short int _value = (1 << a_bitPosition);
    return (a_bitMap & _value) != 0;
}
```

This checks for the a_bitPosition's bit set/unset in a_bitMap and returns true if that specific bit is 1 and false otherwise.

Comment: That will only work for flags; some of the fields in the bitmap consist of more bits, so the bitmap can be `00000000 00010110` where I wanna check if value 5 (101) was set at position 2 with size 3; which it true in this example

Comment: Now I understand your intentention. I think the only thing you can do is optimize. I don't know what your program is doing outside of this function, but maybe you can reduce the amount of operations by moving them out of the function. so for example _shift doesn't have to be calculated every time.